# Custom Dimensions in Universal Analytics firing multiple times

Tags: google-analytics, web-analytics, universal-analytics

I'm not sure if this is an issue or not, but any clarification would be very helpful.

Every time there is a separate event on a page the custom dimensions will fire again (they are first fired during the pageview tag).

On the order confirmation page each custom dimension I have set up for that page is sent at least 4 times. Once on the pageview tag, once for the Event I created, once on the transaction tag and once on the Item tag.

I guess if you are looking at your custom dimensions at a visit level it won't matter but if you are looking at pageviews or hits of the custom dimension this might be an issue.

Does anyone know if this is actually an issue?

Thanks,

Frank

code looks like this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-11111111-1', 'mysite.com');
ga('set', {
      'dimension1': Value1,
      'dimension2': Value2
    });
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('send', 'event',  page type,'Stage x',value);

ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
'id': order id, 
'affiliation': '',
'revenue': revenue total,
'shipping': shipping cost,
'tax': transaction tax
});
```

Comment: Issue i don't know sounds more like over kill to me.  Do you really need to record it that much isn't once enough?

Answer (score 1):

Do you set the value with ga('set'...) ? If so you could try alternative syntax:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'dimension1':  'My Custom Dimension'
});
```

However if the dimensions are session- or user- based it does not IMO make a difference. If they are hit based it depends on what you want to do (e.g if you want to filter/segment events based on hit level custom dimensions you need to send them along with the event, so it is not just  a cosmetical difference).

EDIT
Looking at your code - yes, this is expected behaviour, you are setting the dimension for all subsequent calls. It is not an issue as far as data limits are concerned (custom dimensions do not cause additional interactions). So, not a problem, you will have to decide if you think you need the data (i.e. can your custom dimensions reasonably applied to an event), but even if you don't there are afaik no technical concerns with sending it anyway.

Comment: It is at hit level. I mainly use it to see how many times a certain product page has been viewed or a certain tag type (we group pages like product listing page, product details page, checkout, etc).

At the moment it is set up to send the custom dimension before the pageview (and before the events and transaction and item).

Comment: Thanks Eike, much appreciated. 

So, to send them only once, I would need to place them at the end of the code snippet?

Comment: You can send a configuration object as parameter for all interaction calls. If you set the dimension there (see my example in the answer) the dimension should only be  tracked for that call.